# How can i call robocopy within a python script to bulk copy multiple folders?

Tags: python, windows-7, command-line, copy, robocopy

I am trying to move multiple large folders (> 10 Gb , > 100 sub folders, > 2000 files ) between network drives. I have tried using shutil.copytree command in python which works fine except that it fails to copy a small percentage (< 1 % of files ) for different reasons.

I believe robocopy is the best option for me as i can create a logfile documenting the transfer process. However as i need to copy > 1000 folders manual work is out of question.

So my question is essentially how can i call robocopy (i.e. command line ) from within a python script making sure that logfile is written in an external file.

I am working on a Windows 7 environment and Linux/Unix is out of question due to organizational restrictions. If someone has any other suggestions to bulk copy so many folders with a lot of flexibility they are welcome.

Answer (score 9):

[Subproccess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) allows you to make system calls. This will allow you to call robocopy as you would from the command line.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["robocopy", "basefolder newfolder /S /LOG:mylogfile"])
```

Comment: Putting all the args as a single string can often cause problems. You can split up the strings or pass `shell=True`.

Answer (score 7):

Like halfs13 said use subprocess but you might need to format it like so

```py
from subprocess import call
call(["robocopy", 'fromdir', 'todir', "/S"])
```

Or else it may read the source as everything

Comment: Worth mentioning: `call()` returns the error code. It's worth noting that [both 0 and 1 mean success](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) (so you can't use `check_call()`).

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the `os.exec` family of functions to start any external program:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-management

Probably you want `os.execlp(file, arg0, arg1, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

This put me on the right path but I had to comma separate the options, e.g.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["robocopy", "./", "newfolder/test02", "/S", "/LOG:mylogfile"])
```

This worked a treat. The "/S" copied all subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = 'robocopy.exe {0} {1} /S'.format(srcDir, destPath)
output = subprocess.run(cmd.split(), capture_output=True, text=True)
print(output.stdout)
```

The above snippet will do it.

Note: If `srcDir` and `destPath` has any white space in it, then the `cmd.split()` will not work. Instead you need to do the following:

```
output = subprocess.run(['robocopy.exe',
                         r'<full src path>',
                         r'<full dest path>',
                         '/S'],
                        capture_output=True,
                        text=True)
print(output.stdout)
```

You can read all about subprocess here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Quinton Black and halfs13!

I ended up with this version that accept spaces and non ASCII characters.

```
from subprocess import call
SOURCE="c:\\A path with spaces"
DESTINATION="c:\\Norwegian characters ÆØÅ".encode('UTF-8')
call(["robocopy", SOURCE, DESTINATION, "/S"])
```