# Robocopy python script running whole command as source

Tags: python, robocopy

I have the following line in my script:

```
subprocess.call([r"robocopy", "\\\\stockholm\exam$\ \\\\stockholm\exam_temp$\ /e /move"])
```

Which fails when I run it as Robocopy thinks that the whole line is the source address and has no destination. Could someone tell me what's wrong with my syntax? If I run the same line in CMD (minus the extra \'s etc obviously) it works perfectly!

Many thanks,
Chris.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i call robocopy within a python script to bulk copy multiple folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161659/how-can-i-call-robocopy-within-a-python-script-to-bulk-copy-multiple-folders)

Answer (score 1):

You need to scape de \'s or use raw strings

```
subprocess.call([r"robocopy", r"\\stockholm\exam$\ \\stockholm\exam_temp$\ /e /move"])
```

Answer (score 0):

try to pass args as list, es.

```
subprocess.call([r"robocopy", "\\\\stockholm\exam$\","\\\\stockholm\exam_temp$\","/e","/move"])
```

I'm not not sure about extra \'s.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a list - for e.g.

`command_to_pass = ["robocopy", src, dst, extra_args]`

`call(command_to_pass)`